# Multiple states in one React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't figure out how to use multiple states in a single React component, since I can't call useState in a class.

What I need to achieve is to have multiple states and "monitor" them with useEffect independently.

Currently I have something like this, but from what I understand I can't have anything like useEffect based solely on object fields. How should I go about this?

```
class ShowPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      sorting:'desc',
      lastPostDate:'none',
      hasMore:false,
      pageNumber:1
    };

  }
```

Comment: you can't use `useEffect` in class either

Comment: @decpk so the only way to do what I intend is to rewrite the class as a function?

Comment: Hooks are designed to use in a funcitonal component. So you need to refactor into `functonal` component or use `componentDidMount` lifecycle for `sideEffects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    class ShowPosts extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          posts: [],
          sorting:'desc',
          lastPostDate:'none',
          hasMore:false,
          pageNumber:1
        };
    
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
      //write the code to monitor this.state and prevState in here
}
    
      }


ComponentDidUpdate is called after every render. This will be same as useEffect for functional components.
```